# only in iPhone 6plus simulator - Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, iphone-6-plus

I have a problem in my app , in all simulator it works fine but in iPhone 6plus simulator
I got this message :

```
2014-11-10 11:18:11.651 myApp[14829:8759969] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/roei/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/01F5D8F1-B462-4DA7-90FD-D9F3E7E7EE2A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C8420B33-64D1-4D89-93A5-69324BE6DB88/Symbo.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I try to do this :

1)Make sure your -info.plist has Main story board file based name = MainStoryboard.

2)Right Click on your Story Board file in Xcode and select Delete then References Only

3)Right Click on your project and select Add Files to [Your Project]

4)Navigate to the story board file, found in the en.lproj folder in your projects directory and add it

5)Clean, Recompile and Run and you should find it works.

Got the idea from this SO post: XCode 4.2 MainStoryBoard Not Found

But it did not solve the problem.

I also tried to reset the simulator and clean the progect , but still did not solve the problem.

Please help me (-:

Comment: is this a launch issue or an issue when you reference the storyboard in code?

Comment: Is this a launch issue , when the app start to run in 6+ simulator.

Comment: Finally I made this guide above again and it helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone's still having this problem, what I did to fix it is just:

- Go to the project file
- Click on the target that you're having problem with
- Select `Build Phases`
- In `Copy Bundle Resources`, add your storyboard.